# How to get the next business day if the current date is holiday in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I Need to find out the next business in oracle if the todays date is holiday. There are two different scenarios, need help in writing the logic for these scenarios at once.

If the todays date is 1/17/2022, since it is holiday(Martin Luther King Day) i want to show the date as 1/18/2022 in the output which is nothing but next business day.

If the todays date is 05/31/2021, since it is holiday(Memorial Day), at the time next business falls into next month 01/06/2021. Since it is falling into next month, i want to show the previous business day of holiday 5/28/2021 in the output.

Comment: Do you have a table with a list of holidays?

Comment: Hi , you may want to store the holiday dates in a table and write a function to do the check. The function could be as follows. Write a function which has the date parameter and return the number of days which could be the following
            -- 0 if it is not a holiday ( you could also check for Sat or Sun also)
            -- 1 if it is holiday or Sunday
            -- 2 if it is Saturday 
            -- 3 if it is holiday on Friday and the next working day is Monday

Comment: 1)Store the holidays in one table
2)If the date passed to the function matches with the hoilday then you do the checks , once you get the number then get the date after adding the number of day
3)Check the month if the, IF the month changes after adding days then subtract the INPUT date -1 to get the previous day.

Comment: The linked threads address various working day problems rather than next business day specifically, but the basic solution is the same: maintain a table of public holidays and build queries which use its dates when calculating the offset for business days. You will find it helpful to write standard queries and wrap them in stored (PL/SQL) functions.

Comment: Thanks Himanshu Kandpal, i will follow your suggestion.